# How to prevent check if parent exists for belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActiveRecord automatically checks if the parent exists when saving or creating a child record. Is there a way to prevent this check?

E.g

```
class Project
  has_many :projectitems
end

class Projectitem
  belongs_to :project
end
```

If I now perform an update, I see in the log file:

```
Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 49 LIMIT 1
Projectitems Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE `projectitems` SET .....
```

I do not need to have the check on the parent record. I know it is there and this additional request only causes unnecessary DB load.

Comment: Try `belongs_to :project, optional: true`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. And I must read https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html  where it is obviously documented. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 5 requires `:belongs_to` associations to exist by default. The extra check you are seeing is the validation to ensure that your project still exists.

If you want to switch off this behaviour, you can specify that the relationship is optional:

```
class Projectitem
  belongs_to :project, optional: true
end
```

If you're going to do this, you'd probably want some extra protections in place to ensure that `Projectitems` cannot get "orphaned". For example, if you delete a `Project`, you may wish to also delete all associated project items:

```
class Project
  has_many :projectitems, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Alternatively, you may wish to mark `projectitems.project_id` as a foreign key at the database layer, which can provide the same level of protection as Rails' default validation but for all clients (this is especially useful if your Rails application isn't the only app to connect to the database).

Another alternative (and the one I would personally recommend) is to leave Rails's default alone. It may seem like a disproportionate load on your server when your other database transactions are very simple – but it's really very quick, and is unlikley to slow down; your updates, however, are likely to grow in time as you add more fields and indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hints. I will have to spend some time to check what the performance impact is (surely hardly if the DB sits with the app on the same server, probably different if the DB is a standalone and each request must go over the network too, it adds some latency).